# How to derive the Method of Moments estimator of mu, using the second moment of X, when X is norm distributed?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, estimation, parameter-estimation

If $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ follow a normal distribution, where the variance $\sigma$ is given, how can you derive the MME of the mean $\mu$ using the second moment?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the second moment of $X$ is
$$E[X^2] = \sigma^2 + \mu^2,$$
so by subtracting the known variance from the second moment, you can find the square of the mean.

To this end, compute an estimate of the second moment
$$\hat s = \frac {1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2,$$
then find the estimate of the mean with
$$\hat \mu = \sqrt{\hat s -\sigma^2}.$$

Comment: That's the whole point, the second moment contains information about the mean hat we can extract by subtracting the known variance. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, careless reading.

Comment: First off, thanks for answering! However, I am still a bit confused. We do not know if the mean will be positive or negative, so should it not be +-sqrt(...)? However, this would make it a really bad estimator right?

Comment: Yes, the result of the square root will have two signs; it may also be an imaginary number as you are not guaranteed that $\hat s> \sigma^2$. The reason for the former is that you are loosing sign information by only looking at the square of the data: there is no way to recover if all we have is second-order information. And yes, this will be a pretty bad estimator of the mean!

Comment: Because $X_i$ take only values $0$ and $1,$ it follows that $\sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i.$

Comment: That is a Bernoulli distribution. The question is about the normal distribution. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Comment: That was exactly the answer I was looking for @Riccardo Sven Risuleo. Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: You're welcome @Sam an upvote and an accept would be much appreciated :)